# Maximum likelihood when the data is a function of random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, loss-functions

I am working on a problem that leads to the following equation system
$$
    c_x = Ax - b,
$$
where $A$ is an $n$-by-$p$ matrix of measurements ($p<n$), $b$ is an $n$-by-$1$ vector of measurements and $x$ is a $p$-by-$1$ parameter vector (unknown). Further, I have
$$
    a_j \sim \mathcal{N}(a_j^*, \Sigma_j),
$$
where $a_j$ is the $j$th column of $A$, and
$$
    b \sim \mathcal{N}(b^*, \sigma^2I).
$$
I end up with
$$
    c_x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_x),
$$
in which
$$
    \Sigma_x = \sigma^2D_xD_x^T,
$$
for some known matrix $D_x$, that thus depends on $x$, and where $D^T$ means the transpose of $D$.

Now, I would like to find the parameter vector, $x$, that maximises the likelihood of the data, $c_x$ in this case. I obtain the likelihood function
$$
    \mathcal{L}(c_x|x) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}|\sigma^2D_xD_x^T|^{-1/2}\mathrm{exp}\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(Ax-b)^T(\sigma^2D_xD_x^T)^{-1}(Ax-b)\right\},
$$
for which the negative log-likelihood (times two) is proportional to
$$
    -2\log\mathcal{L}(c_x|x) \propto \log|\sigma^2D_xD_x^T| + (Ax-b)^T(\sigma^2D_xD_x^T)^{-1}(Ax-b) = f(x),
$$
and so I would like to minimise this function, $f$, with respect to the parameter vector $x$.

Now to the problem: When I do this (using `fminunc` in Matlab), the results are really, really poor. They have a very large bias. However, if I remove the log determinant term from the function and only minimise it over the quadratic term the result is instead really, really nice, with hardly any bias (much lower bias than with other approaches, when applied to the underlying problem).

Any ideas about what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Ain't this just a random effects model..? If so, REML estimation is preferred.

Comment: I don't think so, or I don't understand the random effects model.. I have a linear combination of a set of random variables, $A$, and a fixed variable vector, $x$. Aren't the parts of the linear effects model split into random and fixed variables? Perhaps REML would help. Do you know of a good reference for it?